# Playback duration from MF SinkWriter mp4 file is half the time when adding an audio sample also the playback speed of the images is twice as fast

Tags: c#, c++, encoding, mp4, ms-media-foundation

I created a managed c++ library for my c# project to encode images and audio to a mp4 container base on the MSDN tutorial [SinkWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819461(v=vs.85).aspx). To test if the result is ok I created a method that provides 600 frames. This frames represent a 10 second video with 60 frames per second.

The images I provide change every second and my audio file contains a voice that counts to 10.

The problem I am facing is that the output video actualy is only 5 seconds long. The meta data of the video is showing that it is 10 seconds but isn't. Also the voice barely counts up to 5.

If I only write the image samples without the audio part the duration of the video is the expected 10 seconds.

What am I missing here?

**Here are some parts of my application.**

This is the c# part I am using to create the 600 frames and then I call the PushFrame method also in the c# part.

```
var videoFrameCount = 10 * FPS;
SetBinaryImage();

for (int i = 0; i <= videoFrameCount; i++)
{
    // New picture every second
    if (i > 0 &&  i % FPS == 0)
    {
        SetBinaryImage();
    }

    PushFrame();
}
```

The PushFrame method copies the image and audio data to the pointer provided by the SinkWriter. Then I call the PushFrame method of the SinkWriter.

```
private void PushFrame()
{
    try
    {
        encodeStopwatch.Reset();
        encodeStopwatch.Start();

        // Video
        var frameBufferHandler = GCHandle.Alloc(frameBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        frameBufferPtr = frameBufferHandler.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        CopyImageDataToPointer(BinaryImage, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, frameBufferPtr);

        // Audio
        var audioBufferHandler = GCHandle.Alloc(audioBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        audioBufferPtr = audioBufferHandler.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        var readLength = audioBuffer.Length;

        if (BinaryAudio.Length - (audioOffset + audioBuffer.Length) < 0)
        {
            readLength = BinaryAudio.Length - audioOffset;
        }

        if (!EndOfFile)
        {
            Marshal.Copy(BinaryAudio, audioOffset, (IntPtr)audioBufferPtr, readLength);
            audioOffset += audioBuffer.Length;

        }

        if (readLength < audioBuffer.Length && !EndOfFile)
        {
            EndOfFile = true;
        }

        unsafe
        {
            // Copy video data
            var yuv = SinkWriter.VideoCapturerBuffer();
            SinkWriter.Encode((byte*)frameBufferPtr, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, (int)SWPF.SWPF_RGB, yuv);

            // Copy audio data
            var audioDestPtr = SinkWriter.AudioCapturerBuffer();
            SinkWriter.EncodeAudio((byte*)audioBufferPtr, audioDestPtr);

            SinkWriter.PushFrame();
        }

        encodeStopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"YUV frame generated in: {encodeStopwatch.TakeTotalMilliseconds()} ms");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Here are some parts I added to the SinkWriter in c++. The MediaTypes for the audio part are ok I guess because the playback of the audio works.

The rtStart and rtDuration are defined like this:

```
LONGLONG rtStart = 0;
UINT64 rtDuration;
MFFrameRateToAverageTimePerFrame(fps, 1, &rtDuration);
```

The two buffers from the encoders are used like this

```
int SinkWriter::Encode(Byte * rgbBuf, int w, int h, int pxFormat, Byte * yufBuf)
{
    const LONG cbWidth = 4 * VIDEO_WIDTH;
    const DWORD cbBuffer = cbWidth * VIDEO_HEIGHT;

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pFrameBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pFrameBuffer->Lock(&yufBuf, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Calculate the stride
        DWORD bitsPerPixel = GetBitsPerPixel(pxFormat);
        DWORD bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;
        DWORD stride = w * bytesPerPixel;

        // Copy image in yuv pointer
        hr = MFCopyImage(
            yufBuf,                      // Destination buffer.
            stride,                    // Destination stride.
            rgbBuf,     // First row in source image.
            stride,                    // Source stride.
            stride,                    // Image width in bytes.
            h                // Image height in pixels.
        );
    }

    if (pFrameBuffer)
    {
        pFrameBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pFrameBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int SinkWriter::EncodeAudio(Byte * src, Byte * dest)
{
    DWORD samplePerSecond = AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND * AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE * AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS;
    DWORD cbBuffer = samplePerSecond / 1000;

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pAudioBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAudioBuffer->Lock(&dest, NULL, NULL);
    }

    CopyMemory(dest, src, cbBuffer);

    if (pAudioBuffer)
    {
        pAudioBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAudioBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the PushFrame method of the SinkWriter that passes the SinkWriter, streamIndex, audioIndex, rtStart and rtDuration to the WriteFrame method.

```
int SinkWriter::PushFrame()
{
    if (initialized)
    {
        HRESULT hr = WriteFrame(ptrSinkWriter, stream, audio, rtStart, rtDuration);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        rtStart += rtDuration;

        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

And here's the WriteFrame method that combines the video and audio sample.

```
HRESULT SinkWriter::WriteFrame(IMFSinkWriter *pWriter, DWORD streamIndex, DWORD audioStreamIndex, const LONGLONG& rtStart, const LONGLONG& rtDuration)
{
    IMFSample *pVideoSample = NULL;

    // Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSample(&pVideoSample);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pVideoSample->AddBuffer(pFrameBuffer);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        pVideoSample->SetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity, FALSE);
    }
    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pVideoSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pVideoSample->SetSampleDuration(rtDuration);
    }

    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pVideoSample);
    }

    // Audio
    IMFSample *pAudioSample = NULL;

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pAudioSample);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAudioSample->AddBuffer(pAudioBuffer);
    }

    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAudioSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAudioSample->SetSampleDuration(rtDuration);
    }
    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pWriter->WriteSample(audioStreamIndex, pAudioSample);
    }


    SafeRelease(&pVideoSample);
    SafeRelease(&pFrameBuffer);
    SafeRelease(&pAudioSample);
    SafeRelease(&pAudioBuffer);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: `pVideoSample->SetSampleTime` arguments are probably a half of what you'd want. At the very least, you should check this with debugger and rule that out.

Comment: The `SetSampleTime` should be ok because when I remove the AudioSample the duration and time of the video is valid. But I'll try to double the time.
Edit:
I tried to double it but then the creation of the video won't work anymore. After severel frames I takes ages to generate the remaining frames.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the calculation of the buffer size for the audio was wrong.
This is the right calculation:

```
var avgBytesPerSecond = sampleRate * 2 * channels;
var avgBytesPerMillisecond = avgBytesPerSecond / 1000;
var bufferSize = avgBytesPerMillisecond * (1000 / 60);
audioBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

In my question I had the buffer size for one millisecond. So it seems the MF Framework speeds up the images so the audio sounds fine. After I fixed the buffer size the video has exactly the duration I expected and the sound also has no errors.