# Playback speed of video encoded with IMFSinkWriter changes based on width

Tags: c++, winapi, video-capture, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I'm making a screen recorder (without audio) using [Win32s Sink Writer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--using-the-sink-writer-to-encode-video) to encode a series of bitmaps into an MP4 file.

For some reason, the video playback speed increases (seemingly) proportionally with the video width.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711214/playback-duration-from-mf-sinkwriter-mp4-file-is-half-the-time-when-adding-an-au), I've gathered that it's most likely because I'm calculating the buffer size incorrectly. The difference here is that their video playback issue was fixed once the calculation for the audio buffer size was correct, but since I don't encode any audio at all, I'm not sure what to take from it.

I've also tried to read about [how the buffer works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfmediabuffer), but I'm really at a loss as to exactly *how* the buffer size is causing different playback speeds.

[Here is a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SArFyjKE) for the entirity of the code, I really can't track down the problem any more than the buffer size and/or the frame index/duration.

**i.e.:**
Depending on the width of the member variable `m_width` (measured in pixels), the playback speed changes. That is; the higher the width, the faster the video plays, and vice versa.

**Here are two video examples:**
[3840x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96KMP.jpg) and [640x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PTGt.jpg), notice the system clock.
Imugr does not retain the original resolution of the files, but I double checked before uploading, and the program does indeed create files of the claimed resolutions.

rtStart and rtDuration are defined as such, and are both private members of the MP4File class.

```
LONGLONG rtStart = 0;
UINT64   rtDuration;
MFFrameRateToAverageTimePerFrame(m_FPS, 1, &rtDuration);
```

This is where rtStart is updated, and the individual bits of the bitmap is passed to the frame writer.

Moved the `LPVOID` object to private members to hopefully increase performance. Now there's no need for heap allocation every time a frame is appended.

```
HRESULT MP4File::AppendFrame(HBITMAP frame)
{
    HRESULT hr = NULL;

    if (m_isInitialFrame) 
    {
        hr = InitializeMovieCreation();

        if (FAILED(hr))
            return hr;

        m_isInitialFrame = false;
    }

    if (m_hHeap && m_lpBitsBuffer) // Makes sure buffer is initialized
    {
        BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 0;
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

        // Get individual bits from bitmap and loads it into the buffer used by `WriteFrame`
        GetDIBits(m_hDC, frame, 0, 0, NULL, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        GetDIBits(m_hDC, frame, 0, bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, m_lpBitsBuffer, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

        hr = WriteFrame();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            rtStart += rtDuration;
        }
    }

    return m_writeFrameResult = hr;
}
```

And lastly, the frame writer which actually loads the bits into the buffer, and then writes to the Sink Writer.

```
HRESULT MP4File::WriteFrame()
{
    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

    const LONG cbWidth = 4 * m_width;
    const DWORD cbBufferSize = cbWidth * m_height;

    BYTE *pData = NULL;

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBufferSize, &pBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCopyImage(
            pData,                      // Destination buffer.
            cbWidth,                    // Destination stride.
            (BYTE*)m_lpBitsBuffer,      // First row in source image.
            cbWidth,                    // Source stride.
            cbWidth,                    // Image width in bytes.
            m_height                    // Image height in pixels.
        );
    }
    if (pBuffer)
    {
        pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBufferSize);
    }

    // Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
    }

    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(rtDuration);
    }

    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer and update the timestamp
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = m_pSinkWriter->WriteSample(m_streamIndex, pSample);
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);

    return hr;
}
```

A couple details about the encoding:

- Framerate: 30FPS
- Bitrate: 15 000 000
- Output encoding format: H264 (MP4)

Comment: It would be nice to know why the question is getting downvoted. I thought I gave all the relevant information and links to what I've looked at. If anything is missing that I didn't think of, please leave a comment so I can edit the question..

Comment: I guess you could improve the Q though. First of all you could link the recordings you get. Second, it's not clear what are fame index/duration arguments effectively. I guess they are more important than assumed correlation with `m_width` which I don't think has direct effect.

Comment: @RomanR. Thank you for clearing that up. I've now added two video examples clearly demonstrating the drastic effect adjusting the width has, as well as added every bit of code where `rtStart` and `rtDuration` are used. Hopefully that makes my issue easier to understand.

Comment: The presented files have different resolutions, 854x720 and 1280x528

Comment: @RomanR. Sorry, I didn't think the examples had to be of the corresponding resolutions, thought it was just to demonstrate the issue. The links are fixed now and should have the right resolutions.

Comment: Related: my [ScreenCapture](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5256890/ScreenCapture-Single-header-DirectX-library) library might help you since you are using Media Foundation encoding.

Comment: @RomanR. I've tired multiple different ways to implement the frame index/duration now, but everything yields the same result. However, could it possibly have something to do with there not being any audio at all, perhaps? Considering the issue I linked was fixed as soon as the audio came through?

Comment: So... `1` I still don't see 3840x1080 clip; `2` I still think there is no direct impact from width: my guess is that slow processing & incremental timestamps is what you have. It's my educated guess and so far your updates don't invalidate this theory.

Comment: @RomanR. I can see that the clip isn't 3840x1080 from Imugr, but that's most likely because they're compressing it then. Because that's the exact file my program created, and when I look at the details from there, it is indeed 3840x1080. I'm not sure where I can upload it so you see that too. I'll try optimizing it a little more, but I don't see how the video would be faster the bigger the file is if that was the case. And as for the incremental timestamps, that's the exact code that both the other post and the MSDN example uses, but I'll try to look up different ways to get the frame index.

Comment: @RomanR.The code should be more efficient now that it doesn't have to allocate heap memory every time a frame is appened. Further I've found [yet another source] [1] that does the exact same thing as me for the frame index/duration, so I'm really at a loss here..
[1]: [https://www.eternalcoding.com/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this behavior makes sense.

See https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow/tree/master/ScreenCaptureEncode

My program uses DirectX9 instead of GetDIBits, but the behaviour is the same. Try this program with different screen resolutions, to confirm this behaviour.

And I confirm, with my program, the video playback speed increases proportionally with the video width (and also with the video height).

Why ?

More data to copy, more time to pass. And wrong sample time/sample duration.

Using 30 FPS, means one frame each 33.3333333 ms :

- Do GetDIBits, MFCopyImage, WriteSample end exactly at 33.3333333 ms... no.
- Do you write each frame exactly at 33.3333333 ms... no.

So just doing rtStart += rtDuration is wrong, because you don't capture and write screen exactly at this time. And GetDIBits/DirectX9 are not able to process at 30 FPS, trust me. And why Microsoft provided Windows Desktop Duplication (for windows 8/10 only) ?

The key is latency.

Do you know how long GetDIBits, MFCopyImage and WriteSample take ? You should know, to understand the problem. Usually, it takes more than 33.3333333 ms. But it is variable.
You must know it to adjust the correct FPS to the encoder. But you also will need to WriteSample at the right time.

If you use MF_MT_FRAME_RATE with 5-10 FPS instead of 30 FPS, You will see it is more realistic, but not optimal.

For example, use an IMFPresentationClock to handle the correct WriteSample time.

Comment: There it is, the ugly truth. Thank you for pointing this out, I got too distracted with multiple examples doing it this way, I genuinely didn't even consider this. I will definitely be looking more into this, as I now at least know what to look for.

Comment: MSDN states that applications normally don't create this clock, that it should get it from the `IMFMediaSession`, but I don't use such a session. Should I create one, then? Or try to implement a media session?

Comment: Could you post another question for this ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot first, and eventually make a post if I get stuck, will let you know here if I do. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You wellcome. If you search inside all of my github projects, you will find the answer. But I think this is a good question that could help peoples for different kind of project.

Comment: Managed to get it working with the presentation clock!
Made a repository of the completed project here: https://github.com/Henduww/Windows-Screen-Recorder

Might make a Q&A-style post here explaining how I used it, seeing as there's so little information on how to use it for getting the frame timing.